# Spring Boot Application as a Service. System V Init

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, services

I want to run an Spring Boot application as a service in Ubuntu 16.04.
I created a symbolic link to my executable JAR file

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/canperis/core-price-update/menu-core-prices-update-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    /etc/init.d/menu-core-prices-update

$ sudo service menu-core-prices-update start
```

but I have this error:

> Failed to start menu-core-prices-update.service: Unit menu-core-prices-update.service not found.

Comment: If you're on a more recent distro you should be creating a systemd unit file, not a SysV init script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned Ubuntu, most newer versions now support systemd. To set something like this up using systemd you'd create a systemd unit file and then enable it.

#### 1. Software

First decide where you want to locate your software. I'd recommend `/opt/core-price-update`.

Something like this:

```
$ tree /opt/menu-core-prices-update/
/opt/menu-core-prices-update/
├── application.conf
└── menu-core-prices-update-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

0 directories, 2 files
```

#### 2. systemd unit file

Next create a systemd unit file like this:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/menu-core-prices-update.service
[Unit]
Description=Menu Core Prices Update Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="APP_CP=/opt/menu-core-price-update"
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest"
Environment="APP_NAME=com.myapps.MenuCorePriceUpdate"
Environment="APP_NAME_JPROP=appname=menu-core-price-update"
Environment="CONFIG_FILE=/opt/menu-core-price-update/application.conf"
Environment="LOGPATH=/var/log/menu-core-price-update"
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -pm 0755 ${LOGPATH}
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -D${APP_NAME_JPROP} -cp ${APP_CP} ${APP_NAME}"
PIDFile=/run/core-price-update/menu-core-price-update%i.pid
Restart=on-abort
RuntimeDirectory=menu-core-price-update
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
WorkingDirectory=/opt/menu-core-price-update

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### 3. Enable service

To enable this service to run between reboots:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now menu-core-prices-update
```

#### References

- [What's the difference between /usr/lib/systemd/system and /etc/systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd)