# Difference between /usr/lib/systemd/*/*.service and /lib/systemd/*/*.service

Tags: systemd

On Debian some systemd services are installed to `/usr/lib/systemd/*/*.service`, e.g.:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/user/org.gnome.Evince.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent.service
```

Other services (actually much more) are in `/lib/systemd/*/*.service`

```
/lib/systemd/system/networking.service
/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service
/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service
/lib/systemd/system/dm-event.service
/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service
```

There are folders in `/lib/systemd`:

```
/lib/systemd/network/
/lib/systemd/system/
/lib/systemd/system-generators/
/lib/systemd/system-preset/
/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

`/usr/lib/systemd`:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/boot/
/usr/lib/systemd/catalog/
/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/
/usr/lib/systemd/system/
/usr/lib/systemd/user/
/usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/
/usr/lib/systemd/user-generators/
/usr/lib/systemd/user-preset/
```

So, what is the difference of these two directories? [Systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) does not mention `/lib/systemd` at all.

Is it the place chosen by distro or software upstream?
E.g. for Apache [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=apache2.service) uses `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`, [but buildroot](https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/tree/package/apache/apache.mk#n109) `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache.service` (it looks like buildroot also uses `/lib/systemd` at all).

Is it somehow affected by [`/usr` merge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/)?

Everybody cares just about [difference between /usr/lib/systemd/system and /etc/systemd/system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd-system) ([it touches the topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd-system/458252#458252) showing that path for `Units of installed packages` is distro specific – Centos 7 uses `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, Debian `/lib/systemd/system`, but Debian uses both paths).

Answer (score 1):

Sources answer the question, it's really affected by [`/usr` merge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), see `LOOKUP_PATHS_SPLIT_USR`:

[src/portable/portable.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/portable/portable.c#L272): `we force looking inside of /lib/systemd/system/ for units too, as we might be compiled for a split-usr system but the image might be a legacy-usr one`

```
/* Then, send unit file data to the parent (or/and add it to the hashmap).
 * For that we use our usual unit discovery logic. Note that we force looking 
 * inside of /lib/systemd/system/ for units too, as we might be
 * compiled for a split-usr system but the image might be a legacy-usr one. */
r = lookup_paths_init(&paths, UNIT_FILE_SYSTEM, LOOKUP_PATHS_SPLIT_USR, where);
```

(comment reformatted for better readability)

[src/shared/path-lookup.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/shared/path-lookup.c#L596): add `"/lib/systemd/system"` if flag `LOOKUP_PATHS_SPLIT_USR`

```
case UNIT_FILE_SYSTEM:
   add = strv_new(
      /* If you modify this you also want to modify
       * systemdsystemunitpath= in systemd.pc.in! */
      ...
      "/usr/local/lib/systemd/system",
      SYSTEM_DATA_UNIT_PATH,
      "/usr/lib/systemd/system",
      STRV_IFNOTNULL(flags & LOOKUP_PATHS_SPLIT_USR ? "/lib/systemd/system" : NULL),
            ...
```

[src/core/systemd.pc.in](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/systemd.pc.in#L20): `/usr/lib/systemd/system` and `/lib/systemd/system`

```
systemdsystemunitpath=${systemdsystemconfdir}:/etc/systemd/system:\
/run/systemd/system\:/usr/local/lib/systemd/system:${systemdsystemunitdir}\:
/usr/lib/systemd/system:/lib/systemd/system
```

(reformatted for better readability)

Commit message from [799b210267 ("path-lookup: add flag to optionally force checking split-usr unit dirs")](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/799b210267ed6209cd8ba1d693bd49509fab18d8):

```
When we look into a portable service image it might contain the unit
files in split-usr directories rather than merged-usr directories as on
the host. Hence, let#s add a flag that checking all dirs can be forced.
```