# Place user created systemd service files

Tags: systemd

I 've custom systemd service file. Which is the recommended directory?

What is the difference between them?

```
/etc/systemd/system/ 
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206315/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

If you have:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then a link will be placed in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` when you:

```
# systemctl enable myservice.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myservice.service → /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.
```

systemd only uses the links in `multi-user.target.wants/` to know which units to raise when `multi-user.target` is raised.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation.