# systemd-networkd-wait-online.service consistently overwritten by updates

Tags: networking, arch-linux, systemd, systemd-networkd

Arch 5.18.12

I have multiple network interfaces and sometimes it takes a few minutes for all of them to connect. However for system startup I need only one -- which one depends on my geographic location.For *example* sometimes I want to use wifi, sometimes not.

To avoid long startups I modify  the `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` by adding `--any` to the `ExecStart` line.

```
 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

This works a charm.

However on updates this file is overwritten so I have a long startup and then I have to modify the service file again.

Is there a more efficient strategy here?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458252/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller So on Arch I could put my change to `/etc/systemd/system/...` My concern there is that I'd miss an important update to the service file. It looks as if the usual update to systemd will replace the file with no changes, but how would I know?

Comment: I'm thinking an override might work, but can't test it at the moment. (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398540/117549)

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've put the change to a VM, updated systemd -- which overwrote the `/lib/systemd` entry and got a reboot without error. It should *work* but I'm concerned about missin gupdates.

Comment: Well, the trouble is that you're editing a system-provided (packaged) file, so you're bound to lose your updates or the package updates. My best idea was to leave the packaged file alone and simply override the one parameter that you want changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the two ideas from [How to override systemd unit file settings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398540/117549), I would suggest overriding the ExecStart directive by calling `systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`, which will open an editor; put the stanza below into that file, then save and exit the editor:

```bash
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

That command will place a file at /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf with those contents. The doubled ExecStart directive is not a typo; it's important to first clear the existing contents before setting your own.

Because that /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service file is provided by your package manager, you're bound to lose one update or the other:

- changes to files under /lib may be lost during package updates
- changes to the ExecStart directive by the package manager will be overridden by your local override.

It seems to me that the second option is the better choice, since:

- it's in /etc, which should not be affected by package upgrades (so your change won't be completely lost)
- you can add comments to the override file explaining what you're doing and why
- packaged changes to the ExecStart can be merged (or not) into your local override if & when they do happen

If the package decides to rename or otherwise move the `systemd-networkd-wait-online` program, your override would break until you update it (but if that happened, your change to the file in /lib would also be lost and so your functionality would be lost anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can force your manual changes to stay with `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` by running `systemctl daemon-reload`.

*Caveat:* it's important to take any changes you made via `systemctl edit` and add the ones you want to the file in `/lib/systemd/system/` before you run the daemon-reload. In particular:

1. Use `cat /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf` to see your changes;
2. Edit `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`;
3. Delete `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf`;
4. `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. `systemctl restart` the systemd-networkd service.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a `.sh.` file that runs a command and associate it with a service. So, and this is just a patch, you should be able to put that  `ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any` command in a file that will run at startup.
I was reading this the other day about [creating systemd services](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux). You may be able to change the original file to fit what you need, check the bottom of that page where they create/show an example of creating and installing a service for **ethtool**.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking for a systemd-level change. I hope that there is some configuration tweak I can make. See comment by JeffSchaller/ Your solution may work but it is a work-around from outside systemd. Not ideal for my requirements.

Comment: @InjectedScript you have it backwards, actually. See https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path where it describes the files under /etc/ as controlled by the administrator and those under /usr/lib as installed by the package manager.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Obviously no one else posted here, but were you able to get an answer?